# OS X VirtualBox hosting Windows VM as guest: Can the Windows VM be joined to an Active Directory domain?

Tags: windows, macos, networking, virtualbox, active-directory

If so, how? Do I need to do any configuration on OS X itself or should VirtualBox network drivers handle this OOB?

I do not have the ability to test this at the moment, which is why I am asking. Because the answer will determine the implementation prior to acquiring the resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly join a Windows VM to a domain if you are using VirtualBox for Windows, and I'm not aware of any restrictions on the OS X version of VirtualBox that would affect this. In fact, I'm not sure such restrictions would even be possible.

You should be able to do this OOB, as you said. You may have to configure the virtual network adapter for your specific environment, but this is handled within VirtualBox so there shouldn't be any configuration required in OS X itself.

Comment: You'd probably need to set the network adapter to Bridged, in order to get an IP on the same subnet as the host and minimize potential issues.  This MAY be necessary in order to communicate with a domain controller, depending as @toryan said, on your environment.